# How is the username and password captured on this mobile device?

Tags: encryption, tls, passwords, email, android

I have a Motorola phone, and I am concerned about my privacy after reading this article : http://www.beneaththewaves.net/Projects/Motorola_Is_Listening.html

The poster says:

> For both of these services, the email address and password for the
>   account are sent to Motorola. Both services support a mechanism
>   (oAuth) explicitly intended to make this unnecessary, but Motorola
>   does not use that more-secure mechanism. The password is only sent
>   over HTTPS, so at least it can't be easily intercepted by most third
>   parties

I would like to know, despite the SSL encrypted connections to Twitter and Facebook, how was Motorola able to collect the email and passwords?

Which leads me onto the question, does the default android email client not protect information, even if it is sent over TLS/SSL on ports 465/993? If some mega company made your phone, and installed their custom rom onto it, would they then be able to circumvent any security mechanism provided by the AOSP base software? If so, what is the solution?

Comment: I think Motorola will capture the email/password when you enter that on the Email application made by Motorola.

Comment: @ThoriumBR but the majority of apps that Motorola captures credentials for are not made by Motorola, eg. Facebook, Twitter, Youtube...

Comment: I haven't dig into anything but its possible that is a software/component installed that sniff into the traffic...if you have root you can download a firewall to block anything from motorola to connecting to internet.

Comment: Or They can be using some certificate to snoop into https traffic

Answer (score -1):

This is explained by the first, second, and third [immutable laws of security](http://blogs.technet.com/b/rhalbheer/archive/2011/06/16/ten-immutable-laws-of-security-version-2-0.aspx):

- If a bad guy can persuade you to run his program on your computer, it's not solely your computer anymore.
- If a bad guy can alter the operating system on your computer, it's not your computer anymore.
- If a bad guy has unrestricted physical access to your computer, it's not your computer anymore.